# why screen as black screen ,red border in micromax canvas juice 3plus

Tags: screen

I bought a micromax canvas juice3plus 8 months before. Now screen became  black in color with red border.. How to correct this

Comment: Can you take a photo of the phone's screen and post it here?

Answer (score 0):

This is a hardware problem. You need to take your phone to a repair shop and get the screen fixed.